# Crypto/webcrypto is undefined in production deployment

Tags: javascript, next.js, webcrypto-api

In a `Next.js` [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction), I import [webcrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) as follows:

```
import { webcrypto } from 'crypto'
```

Later, this is used as follows:

```
const random = webcrypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(8))
```

This works fine when I test on `localhost`, but as soon as I deploy to production (on Vercel), I get the following error:

```
ERROR   [next-auth][error][SIGNIN_EMAIL_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_email_error Cannot read property 'getRandomValues' of undefined {
  error: {
    message: "Cannot read property 'getRandomValues' of undefined",
    stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRandomValues' of undefined\n" +
      '    at Object.generateVerificationToken (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/696.js:97:78)\n' +
      '    at email (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/email/signin.js:22:188)\n' +
      '    at Object.signin (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:117:50)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:238:26)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthNextHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:23:19)\n' +
      '    at async /var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:59:32\n' +
      '    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:182:9)\n' +
      '    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:386:9)\n' +
      '    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:488:37)',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  providerId: 'email',
  message: "Cannot read property 'getRandomValues' of undefined"
}
```

Where this is the key problem:

```
message: "Cannot read property 'getRandomValues' of undefined"
```

Why would this not work when deployed, but work fine on `localhost`? What can I do to get it working?

Note: the deployment uses `https`

Comment: Probably different versions of node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume in prod you have Node version lover than 15.0.0. Because from [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API#browser_compatibility) you provided it stated that that method is supported from v15